# Calling relationship returns error "maximum execution time of 60sec"

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a model `User` which has a relationship to `Notification`.

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $with = ['notifications'];

    # relationship methods

    public function notifications() //my notifications
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Notification::class, 'subject_id');
    }

    public function notify() //to create a notifications to other user
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Notification::class, 'causer_id');
    }

    # other methods

    public function unreadNotifications()
    {
        return $this->notifications->filter(function($n){
            return $n->seen==0;
        });
    }

    public function sendNotification($subject, $data)
    {
        $this->notify()->create(['subject_id' => $subject->id, 'title' => $data['title'], 'description' => $data['description']]);
    }
}
```

---

**EDITED**

```
class Notification extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function causer()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'causer_id');
    }

    public function subject()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'subject_id');
    }
}
```

After I make that `unreadNotifications` method it starts to fail:

> Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Even just calling `$this->notifications` it still fails. Somebody knows how to fix these?

Comment: Have you tried echoing the sql query generated by the relationship?

Comment: How much data is in the notifications table? Do you have any indexes on this table?

Comment: Edit quesion with `Notification::class` code.

Comment: @Jerodev I have 2 sample data. And I didn't `index` nor `foreign` it in my migration. Slr Sir

Comment: In failing method, try this way `return $this->notifications()->filter(function($n){ return $n->seen==0; });`.

Answer (score -1):

Set this on top of your script

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes
ini_set('max_execution_time', '0'); // for infinite time of execution
```

Or set this in your php.ini file and restart you Apache service

```
max_execution_time = 0
```

Comment: looking for model relationship solution Sir. Thanks for the respo though.